# How to achieve this underline or bottom border effect without editing line-height?

Tags: html, css

[image: like the orange underline here]

I would like to achieve this underline, but without messing the line height.

If I use text-decoration:underline; its too close to the text, not visually appealing, and if I use bottom-border its too far away and on the edge because of line height.

Is there any other HTML&CSS solution or workaround except changing the line height?

Comment: pseudo-elements `:before or :after`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I sometimes use an :after or :before pseudo element for that sort of thing. That way I can be knit picky about how far away it is.

The pseudo element can be absolute positioned to ensure that.

So for a general example:

```
.nav-bar-item:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    height: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: orange;
    display: none;
}
.nav-bar-item:hover:after {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: This is precisely the answer that I would give, but I personally would always display the pseudo element with `display: block;` and instead have it hidden with `opacity: 0`, and then change it back to `opacity:1` on the `:hover` state. This has the extra benefit of giving you the opportunity to transition the opacity to add some sort of effect.

Comment: exactly :) just wanted a basic template out there to get the juices flowing but yeah there's opportunity for cool transitions and animations that would match your app/site style

Comment: Thanks, any idea why doesn't it work in this pen?  

http://codepen.io/simii/pen/kkpoRv

Comment: oops yeah it's background-color instead of color

Answer (score 1):

If you set the main element (the "Services" link in your image) to `position: relative`, you could then employ the :before or :after pseudo elements of that item, set with `position: absolute` and the top/left/right/bottom positioning values.